# I hold a multi-entry Schengen visa. Would the airline let me board a Schengen-bound flight if my return flight is on a different airline?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, check-in, proof-of-onward-travel

Ok, worried by [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57459/refused-boarding-with-lufthansa-because-i-didnt-have-a-valid-return-ticket-any), my situation is:

1. Have valid multiple entry Schengen visa, first trip already made to issuing country.
2. DOH-ORY one way ticket with Pegasus, with 3 hour stay at SAW, so entry into Schengen at Paris. Stay for 5 days.
3. CDG-IST direct one way ticket with Atlas Global, Have Turkish tourist visa. Stay for 5 days. So, Exit from Schengen at Paris again.
4. SAW-DOH direct one way with again Pegasus airlines.
5. Nationality Indian, Residency Qatar, Schengen Visa by embassy in Qatar.

Can/will check-in desk agent at Doha object for my boarding detailed in point 2 (& Atlas G agent at CDG for Turkey in point 3)? I have all required hotel bookings for Paris and Istanbul. Any Timatic or other official quotations will be appreciated.

Can we enter Schengen (and/or Turkey) by two one-way tickets on different airlines?

*On mobile, so T.SE did not offer me similar questions, but will search around*

Comment: Hmm.. ok, so how can I be better prepared to deal with agent in case I encounter this, afaik, there is no legal requirement that exit should be on same airline, but any proof? Thx

Comment: Ok, I get now a bit.. also the text on Timatic with my details say: `-Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their stay and documents required for their next destination.` So, I think I could ask for supervisor if gate agent does not get the meaning of this printout from timatic..

Comment: :) I mean in 2004 Indian Airlines agent sent me to Immigration (or Emigration?) Desk to make sure if I can get visa on arrival in Kenya. Those guys, rightfully, said they dont care about me in Kenya, all they are is if I have proper documents to exit India. Airline agent was like No, get them to write it, Immigration was like no way, not our scope, then airline supervisor read all of my Wikipedia, Kenyan Embassy email prints, and instructed the girl to print boarding passes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can we enter Schengen (and/or Turkey) by two one-way tickets on different airlines?

Yes you can enter with a one way ticket in Schengen or turkey on
different airlines. I have entered multiple times in Schengen, UK and
Turkey with one-way ticket. Your all airline tickets can be with
different airlines as long as you provide your next/return ticket to
airline counter or immigration when entering into Schengen/Turkey.

Recently this year I flew through Etihad Airways with 1 ticket from:

24 Feb: KHI  TO ABU DHABI

24 Feb: Abu Dhabi to Rome (Schengen 10 hours layover which I entered and exit)

24 Feb: Rome to LHR

[image]

All the time I was asked for my return ticket at airport in KHI also at immigration in Rome and London. Simply I provided my return ticket from Pegasus airline from London to Istanbul with different airline and never faced any problem.

This was my return flight Pegasus airline from London Gatwick to SAW:

[image]

So shortly neither airline nor immigration has any issues regarding
different booking as long as you provide your complete flight
tickets/boarding passes for your entire journey. Also there is no such rule that you must use the same airline for your return journey.